# how to i add views to linear layout in upward direction?

Tags: android-layout

I am using Linear Layout to display image view and text view.

I am getting the response from server by using XML parsing.

When i am getting the new  response from server the second image view and related text will be displayed in the bottom of the new Layout and so on.

but i want to display the image with related text in the above of the previous Layout.

if any one see this question, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it programmatically with:

LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout .addView(newView, index);
You just have to add always with index = 0